# sql query to match people based on interests

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 3 tables.

- Mentors Table (id,interest,location)
- Mentees Table (id,interest,location)
- Interests Table (interests)

I want to assign mentees to mentors. How do I match them ?

Also I was thinking of have one table for both the mentees and mentors.

Users Table(id,interest,location,role)

In this case will the querying be difficult ?

Thanks.

Comment: Just join the Mentors and Mentees tables to each other. The Interests table is irrelevant.

Comment: Is it possible that somebody could have more than 1 interest?  I would assume so. Will it also be possible that someone could be a mentor in one interest and a mentee in another? I suppose in life that could happen as well.

Answer (score 2):

Just join the two tables to find mentors and mentees that are in the same location and have the same interests.

```
SELECT t1.id AS Mentor_ID, t2.id AS Mentee_ID
FROM Mentors AS t1
JOIN Mentees AS t2 ON t1.interest = t2.interest AND t1.location = t2.location
```